# Internet Explorer 11 always crashes whenever Developer Tools is opened when working with an Angular Project

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, developer-tools

So, I've had this issue for days now. That IE will always crash when Developer Tools is opened when working with my angular application. And I'm adding this question since I could not see a solution on stackoverflow of how to deal with this particular issue. (At least when searching with this question as query) And it seems a problem even with Windows 10s Nov 2018 Update. BTW. I'm on the latest beta of WIndows 10, which should have the latest updates for IE should this be a bug on IE 11 really, but to no luck, IE still crashes even on the beta build.

So for a while, I resorted to installing Windows 7 and IE 11 inside Hyper-V and just debugged my angular application inside Hyper-V while making my code Changes in Windows 10 with my IDE IntelliJ. How did I do that?, just follow the instructions from this link.

---

[Debugged Angular Application on a Virtual Machine / Hyper-V](http://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2014/11/24/debugging-iis-express-website-from-a-hyperv-virtual-machine/)

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make it simple, just do the ff.:

Go to Internet Explorer then click

- Settings button > Internet Options > Advance > Security >

  ○ then  on the Settings view, select/check "Enable 64-bit processes for Enhanced Protected Mode"

Close the browser then open I.E again.

You should then be able to Open Developer Tools now without I.E Crashing.

---

Optional step if the issue still persist.

- Go to your run command and then type the ff.

  iexplorer.exe -extoff